# Mongodb : array element projection with findOneAndUpdate doesn't work?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am using Mongoose and I'm trying to update an array element and get it back updated.
This is my document structure :

```
{   name:String,
    friends:[
        {   name:String,
            age:Number
        }
    ]
}
```

When I execute the following query I get all the friends in the result but I only want to get 25 year old friends back :

```
theCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {   name : 'cherif',
        'friends.name':'kevin'
    },
    {   $set:{
            'friends.$.age':25
        }
    },
    {   friends:
        {   $elemMatch:
            {   age : 25 } 
        }
    },
    function(err,result){
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result);
        }});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) for `findOneAndUpdate` specify, you need to include your projection object as the `select` property of the `options` parameter:

```js
theCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {   name : 'cherif',
        'friends.name':'kevin'
    },
    {   $set:{
            'friends.$.age':25
        }
    },
    {   select: { 
            friends: {
               $elemMatch: 
               {   age : 25 } 
            }
        }
    },
    function(err,result){
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is it possible to use $ projection here? For example `Doc.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id, 'comments._id': cmtId }, {...}, { select: 'comments.$': 1 })`. I've tried this but strangely it returned `{ comments: [{}, {}, {}], _id:... }`

Comment: @KwiZ Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to use $ projection in the same way but with no luck!

Comment: @admrply Go ahead and post a new question with the full details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: the answer to @KwiZ  is use 0 instead of $   ( { select: 'comments.0': 1 })