# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate -- updating an object inside an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Take a look at this Schema:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
email: { type: String, required: true },
password: { type: String, required: true },
books: [{
    cover: String,
    title: String,
    link: String,
    requests: { requestingUser: String, bookOffered: String, 
    beingRequested: false }
}],
ip: String
});
```

What I am trying to do is use `findOneAndUpdate` to (based on given information) find the correct user, and then find the correct book (from the array of books by given title) And update the requests field (which is another object.) Is this possible to accomplish with only one `findOneAndUpdate` query ?

So far my finding has been that I would have to do a `findOne` to get the correct user, and then do a `findOneAndUpdate` nested inside that. Is there a way to do this with one query command?

Thanks

Comment: Something like `findOneAndUpdate({"email" : emailvalue, "books.title" : titlevalue}, { "books.$.requests.requestingUser" : uservalue }, ...`

Comment: Yea it worked now, don't know why it wasn't working before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb : array element projection with findOneAndUpdate doesn't work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986505/mongodb-array-element-projection-with-findoneandupdate-doesnt-work)