# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate: update an object in an array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the exact same issue as described in this thread (hence the similar title): [Mongoose findOneAndUpdate -- updating an object inside an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128561/mongoose-findoneandupdate-updating-an-object-inside-an-array-of-objects)

Given this model:

```
const SavedFoodsSchema = new Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  list: [
    {
      id: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      points: { type: Number, required: true }
    }
  ]
})
```

I wrote the following function just to test finding a document in the SavedFoods Collection based on the userId param, and then in the `list` array, for the first object in the array, setting the `name` to "Something else".

```
function updateFood (userId) {
  // This didn't work
  SavedFoods.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      id: userId,
      'list.id': 0
    },
    {
      $set: {
        'list.$.name': 'Something else'
      }
    },
    null,
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err)
      } else {
        console.log('Updated', userId)
      }
      process.exit(0)
    }
  )
}
```

The callback is called and there is no error, however the the changes do not get reflected in my db.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `id: userId` or `user: userId` is this ok? because your query seems to be ok...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thank you so much! "id" was indeed incorrect, the field was actually "user" as you suggested - it now works perfectly. If you'd like to add this as an answer, I'll choose it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mismatched `id` and `user` field

Try to change `id` with `user`

```
SavedFoods.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      user: userId,
      'list.id': 0
    }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so I just delete `$set` from `.findOneAndUpdate`

Example:

```
function updateFood (userId) {
  SavedFoods.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      id: userId,
      'list.id': 0
    },
    {
      {'list.$.name': 'Something else'}
    },
    null,
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err)
      } else {
        console.log('Updated', userId)
      }
      process.exit(0)
    }
  )
}
```

Works for me.