# NodeJS MongoDB Projection not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm

I made a findOneAndUpdate on NodeJS with the following Code

```
var themessageid = "ID of message A"
workstreamchat.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'chat.sidmessage': themessageid }, 
    { '$set': { 
        'chat.$.linkinfo': linkinfo 
    } }, 
    { returnOriginal: false }, 
    function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);            
    }
);
```

e.g of document returned

```
{
    "_id": "mongoid",
    "chat": [
        {
            "sidmessage": "id_of_message_A",
            "usersid": "38jrc05h14avm14e",
            "messageinfo": {
                "text": "Message A"
            }, 
            "linkinfo": "something" 
        },
        {
            "sidmessage": "id_of_message_B",
            "usersid": "38jrc05h14avm14e",
            "messageinfo": {
                "text": "MessageB"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It works flawlessly and returns the updated document with the updated specific object in the whole array.

The problem is I wanted to use projection to return the chat array only with the updated document. I have tried

```
{ projection: { 'chat.$': 1 }, returnOriginal: false }
```

and

```
{ projection: { chat: chat.$ }, returnOriginal: false }
```

But everytime this kind of projection with `returnOriginal` returns null.

e.g of expected document

```
{
    "_id": "mongoid", 
    "chat": [
        {
            "sidmessage": "id_of_message_A",
            "usersid": "38jrc05h14avm14e",
            "messageinfo": {
                "text": "Message A"
            },
            "linkinfo": "something"
        }
    ],
}
```

**Notes:**

The [documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) I am using.

My npm version is 6.4.0

My MongoDB driver version is 3.1.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb : array element projection with findOneAndUpdate doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986505/mongodb-array-element-projection-with-findoneandupdate-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer after testing multiple cases.

What i needed was.

```
{
     projection: { 
          chat: { 
              $elemMatch: { sidmessage: new ObjectId(id_of_message_A) } 
          }
     }, 
     returnOriginal: false 
}
```